# Concatenate first fields of multiple objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

Is there a way in javascript to concatenate named/indexed fields (say one field of each object) of multiple objects to a string.

```
var theArray = [{
 field1: "TEXT",
 field2: "VAL"
 ...
},
{
 field1: "text",
 field2: "val"
 ...
}
...
];
```

I would like for the sake of ideomacy (ideomatic programming) to know if there's a way to concatenate values of all `field1` in an array WITHOUT a for loop.

Something like

```
theArray.getFieldValues[0].join(', ');
```

#### Which options do we have here?

- overload Array - wouldn't do that,
- helper function - don't wanna loops.

There're filter and grep functions in jQuery, but they only filter the elements, I would like to know if there's already something like

```
theArray.grepNewObject(function(o){ return o.field1; }).join(', ');
```

Comment: may be `forEach` , take a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: @Cherniv I like that, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) first to get an array of just `field1` and then [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Join) it:

```
theArray.map(function(x){return x.field1}).join(', ');
```

Note that map needs to be shimmed in IE 8 and earlier. Alternatively, since you're using jQuery, you can use [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) for a cross-browser solution:

```
$.map(theArray, function(x){return x.field1}).join(', ');
```